# How to get newline and Umlaut correctly from a socket message

Tags: python, unicode, utf-8, decoding

I receive information on a socket like this:

```
import socket

s = socket.socket()

while True:
   try:
      data = self.s.recv(1024)
      answer = data.decode()
                
      print(answer)

      if data.decode() != "":
         break

   except socket.timeout:
      break
```

The information which gets sent includes information about new lines and also german Umlaute (Ä, Ö, Ü, etc.). How can I get both printed correctly? Let's assume the text which is received is `"Äpfel fallen \n nicht weit vom Stamm"`. If my code stays as above, it prints exactly this:

```
Äpfel fallen \n nicht weit vom Stamm
```

I read that I could use `decode('unicode_escape')` to properly handle the newline, but since unicode can't handle Umlaute, my result then looks like this:

```
Ã„pfel fallen 
 nicht weit vom Stamm
```

How can I achieve my desired result:

```
Äpfel fallen 
 nicht weit vom Stamm
```

**Edit:**
If I print `data`, it looks like this:

```
b'\xc3\x84pfel fallen \\n nicht weit vom Stamm'
```

Comment: Won't something like this not already fix it? `' '.join([i.strip() for i in 'Äpfel fallen \n nicht weit vom Stamm'.split()])`

Comment: Portuguese? It's a [mojibake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake) case: `['ÄÖ'.encode(enc).decode('cp860') for enc in ['cp437', 'cp775', 'cp850', 'cp852', 'cp857', 'cp858', 'cp861', 'cp865']]` returns `['ÃÕ', 'ÃÕ', 'ÃÕ', 'ÃÕ', 'ÃÕ', 'ÃÕ', 'ÃÕ', 'ÃÕ']`

Comment: To be clear on what is received, what does `print(data)` look like (before decode)?

Comment: @RJAdriaansen: That does not seem to work. If I use that on my answer string, it just leads to the same result.

I updated the question to contain the printed data.

Comment: What about this: `' '.join([i.strip() for i in b'\xc3\x84pfel fallen \\n nicht weit vom Stamm'.decode("utf-8").encode('cp1252').decode('unicode-escape').split()])`

Comment: https://nedbatchelder.com/text/unipain.html nicely summarizes how you need to understand how the `bytes` on a socket correspond to Unicode strings and how you need to `encode` strings to `bytes` and vice versa with `decode`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution which works well enough for my case. By adding `.replace(r"\n","\n")` when saving the answer, I jsut replace the raw string with the correct symbol for the newline without needing to decode/encode any further. This could also easily be extended by other symbols (\t, etc.).

```
import socket

s = socket.socket()

while True:
   try:
      data = self.s.recv(1024)
      answer = data.decode().replace(r"\n","\n")  
                
      if data.decode() != "":
         break

   except socket.timeout:
      break
```